# Convert an existing type into an anonymous type and add a new property

Tags: vb.net, clone, anonymous-types

Is it possible to take an existing type and create an anonymous type from it with additional properties? For Example (in VB)

```
Public Class Person
  Public Name As String
  Public Age As Integer
End Class

Dim p As New Person With {.Name = "James", .Age = 100}

Dim n = New With {.ShoeSize = 10}
```

What I want is the second object (n) to clone all the properties of p and then add a new property (ShoeSize).

Is this possible?

Many Thanks

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax to do that in C#. You'll have to construct the anonymous type yourself, with all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this regularly, a modification of my extensions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937187/256431) could save some typing.

That is, if they returned `string.Join(", " , from p in ps select "." + p.Name + " = " + VarName + "." + p.Name)`, you could at least save some typing.

An example with the variables in the OP: `p.AllFieldsVb("p")` returns `".Name = p.Name, .Age = p.Age"`.