# Extend an existing (anonymous) type in a select query

Tags: .net, select, anonymous-class

While working with LinqPad I have a `Select x, Extra=f(y)` query where I'd like to return all the properties (and fields) of `x` at the same level as `Extra`, rather than as separate `x` and `Extra` properties (or fields).

Can this be done?

I.e. I want `Select x.p1, x.p2, Extra=f(y)` without having to type that much.

Note the type of `x` may or may not actually be anonymous, just somewhat opaque or just too big to copy out manually. The type resulting from the VB.NET implicit typing and the C# explicit `new {}` is anonymous.

Comment: This question is not so clear even if your answer sheds some light on it. So a new anonymous type with both types as properties is not sufficient? `select new { x, y }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is the c# version of my VB.NET example (if you meant `f(y)`, not just `y`). But, yes, I stopped for tea. I should add examples of what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Skeet has already answered this question negatively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233730/256431) (but that question is not a duplicate because it's a special case).

As a workaround here are `My Extensions` to at least list the properties and fields ready to be pasted back into the `Select` query.

```cs
// Properties so you can "extend" anonymous types
public static string AllProperties<T>(this T obj, string VarName)
{
    var ps=typeof(T).GetProperties();
    return ps.Any()?(VarName + "." + string.Join(", " + VarName + ".", from p in ps select p.Name)):"";
}

// Fields so you can "extend" anonymous types
public static string AllFields<T>(this T obj, string VarName)
{
    var fs=typeof(T).GetFields();
    return fs.Any()?(VarName + "." + string.Join(", " + VarName + ".", from f in fs select f.Name)):"";
}
```

You may be lucky enough to just be able to say `Select x.AllProperties("x") Take 1` but when you need to avoid Linq-to-SQL getting in the way you need to add more: `(from ... Select x).First().AllProperties("x")`, with even more hoops if you need to get both properties and fields (as I found you do with the entities generated by LinqPad).

These will produce a string like `"x.p1, x.p2"` that can be pasted back into the original `Select` query.